# React error is not displayed on browser, only getting an empty screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

React is only showing an empty screen rather than showing an error something like this on my instructor's system:
[image]

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I can definitely see the error in the console and in IDE but to test error boundaries I want to fix this. Currently, When I use error boundary and create my own error using throw new Error(), error boundary only console.logs the error but doesn't display the UI, my screen only gets freezed.

ON USING ERROR BOUNDARIES:
App.js:

```
import UserFinder from './components/UserFinder';
import UsersContext from './store/user-context';
import ErrorBoundary from './components/ErrorBoundary';

const DUMMY_USERS = [
  { id: 'u1', name: 'Max' },
  { id: 'u2', name: 'Manuel' },
  { id: 'u3', name: 'Julie' },
];

function App() {
  const usersContext = {
    users: DUMMY_USERS
  }

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={usersContext}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <UserFinder />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ErrorBoundary.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            hasError: false
        }
    }

    componentDidCatch(error){
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({hasError:true});
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasError === true)
        {
            <p>Error Occured!</p>
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Users.js(where I generated error)

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import User from './User';
import classes from './Users.module.css';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showUsers: true
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.users.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('No user Provided');
    }
  }

  toggleUsersHandler() {
    this.setState((currState) => {
      return {
        showUsers: !currState.showUsers
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const usersList = (
      <ul>
        {this.props.users.map((user) => (
          <User key={user.id} name={user.name} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.users}>
        <button onClick={this.toggleUsersHandler.bind(this)}>
          {this.state.showUsers ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Users
        </button>
        {this.state.showUsers && usersList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

SO WHEN I TYPE A NAME WHICH IS NOT IN THE USER-LIST, Users.js gets an error. I used error boundaries to display a paragraph saying "something went wrong". But on generating an error, My screen freezes, rather than showing a paragraph. Error boundary is working fine because my app doesn't crash (doesn't show blank screen like first screenshot), this time it only freezes my screen.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: Do you mean errors in development server, or in production bundle file?

Comment: check your console for the error, use ctrl + shift + i (windows) or option + command + i (mac)

Comment: EDIT: I can definitely see the error in the console and in IDE but to test error boundaries I want to fix this. Currently, When I use error boundary and create my own error using throw new Error(), error boundary only console.logs the error but doesn't display the UI, my screen only gets freezed. All of this is happening during development

Comment: check console. open it by inspect element. often the empty screen means  when you have logical error.

Comment: It might help to share your error boundary component and a sample of how you are using it

Comment: Added components @secan

Comment: If the error is thrown by the `Users` component, shouldn't the `ErrorBoundary` component wrap `Users` rather than `UserFinder`? In this simplified example, everything seems to work as expected if you wrap the correct component: https://jsfiddle.net/wcvkp65j/1/

Comment: I'll make sure that I wrap the correct components thanks @secan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `render` method of the `ErrorBoundary`, you do not `return` the message.

```
render() {
  if (this.state.hasError === true) {
    return <p>Error Occured!</p>;
  }
  return this.props.children;
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I did not notice the missing `return`

Comment: Wow I really didn't see that, thanks alot!

Comment: Same error in function components... What to do